# Java Url Validation With Placeholders

Tags: java, regex, validation, url

I have built an API where you can register a callback URL.

The URL's are validated using the Apache [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) class.

I now have to add a feature that allow to add placeholders in the configured URL.

```
https:/foo.com/${placeholder1}/bar/${placeholder2}
```

These placeholders will be dynamically replaced using the Apache [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) or something similar.

Now my issue, **how do I validate the URL's with the placeholders ?**

I have thought of a solution :

- I replace the expected placeholders with an example value
- Then I Validate the URL using the Apache [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html)

My issue with this solution is that the Apache [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) only returns a boolean so the error message will be quite ambiguous.

**Is there another solution than creating my own regex ?**

**Update :** following discussions in the comments

There is a finite number of allowed placeholders.

The format of the Strings that will replace the placeholders is also known.

The first objective is to be able to check if the given URL which eventually contains placeholders is valid at the time it is configured.

The second objective is, if the URL is not valid return an intelligible error message.

There are multiple error cases :

- A placeholder used in the URL is not in the allowed placeholder list
- The URL in not valid independently of the placeholders

Comment: **When** are you going to validate: before or after the substitution?

Comment: Before the substitution, when the callback configuration is created.
The placeholders are known, I may do a sample substitution.

Comment: Are you going to sanitize replacement strings separately? Let say you have a good skeleton and then use something like `":::::"` as the replacement?

Comment: The replacement strings are already specified and sanitized (serial numbers and ids...).

Comment: Is this `https:/foo.com/` a valid url ? Also, where do you expect the placeholder's to be within the url ?

Comment: A simple validator is `^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$` but as you can see `(?:/[^\s]*)?` covers all the terms after the domain where not whitespace `[^\s]` generally matches many character(s).

Comment: @sln the `https:/foo.com/...` url should be valid. I have refined the issue.

Comment: @A.Malle - I think you're missing my point(s) `${placeholder1}` is easy to parse and include in any/all parts of a url regex, _if that sequence of characters_ would not otherwise be valid in a url, which they must not be. So to require them just be in  directory segments is reasonable. This is not rocket science. Just get a good url regex and add regex to it, no need to be extravagant.

Comment: @sln I get the idea of the regex. But I don't think (a sigle) regex gives me easy ways to easily return comprehensible error messages. For that I would have to have several of them and that would start to get complicated. I have implemented a validator using `java.net.URL`, `java.net.URI` and some simple regex for allowed placeholders validation. I understand that my solution is basically multiple regex, but I don't have to test them and maintain them as much as custom regex...

Comment: You're overthinking error reporting. The idea is to parse the url with a regex that matches the _known_ places for Placeholders. I assume you control _where_ the placeholders can be in the url, right? Once you setup where the placeholders can be, if the regex matches, _it's a valid url_. And .. after the match, you have captured the placeholders. You use the capture group at that point to analyze the placeholders-keys to see if they exist, and to do reaplacements when needed. It's all a single regex, with a single match. And a single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimal URL validation, you could use the `java.net.URL` constructor (it will work with your `https:/foo.com/${placeholder1}/bar/${placeholder2}` example).

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), it throws:

> **MalformedURLException** - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.

You can then leverage the `URL` methods as a bonus, to get parts of it such as path, protocol, etc.

I would definitely advise against re-inventing the wheel with regex for URL validation.

Note that `java.net.URI` has a much stricter validation and would fail your example with placeholders as is.

**Edit**

As discussed, since you need to validate placeholders as well, you probably want to actually try to fill them first and fail fast if something's wrong, then proceed and validate the populated URL against `java.net.URI`, for strict validation.

**General caveat**

You might also want to make your life easier and leverage an existing framework that would allow you to use annotated path variables in the first place (e.g. `Spring`, etc.), but that's quite a broad discussion.

Comment: I should have added that there is a list of "allowed" placeholders and I want to check that only those are used.

Comment: @A.Malle and are you doing that originally by configuring the `UrlValidator`?

Comment: the placeholders handling is part of the new feature. 
For now the URL's did not allowed any placeholders.

Comment: @A.Malle right, so you *could* use `URL` for the basics, then regex to validate anything found in between `${` and `}` (reluctantly matched), against a set of accepted placeholders. Of course, things would get more complicated if there was a possibility to have "malformed" placeholders and such like. Or, you could try and populate with `StrSubstitutor`, fail fast if something wrong happens, and otherwise validate against the end result with stricter `URI`.

Comment: however if I use `java.net.url` for the validation with the placeholders, then I just check the placeholders with a regex... 
That may not be too ugly ?

Comment: @A.Malle yeah it would look ugly, and probably incomplete too (since you're not going to check on the placeholder syntax).